# tensorRT and tf.while_loop

Tags: tensorrt

I'm converting a custom model to TensorRT that contains a 'while_loop'. The 'while_loop' iterates through a fix number of steps.

This GIT post states TensorRT has an issue with while_loop:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorrt/issues/87

The current error I'm getting is. This error corresponds to the temporary variable I'm creating in the while loop.

```
uff.model.exceptions.UffException: Const node conversion requested, but node is not Const
```

Does TensorRT support while_loops? My code is implemented in TF 1.14. If not, would TensorRT support a for loop implemented in TF 2.0?

I'm able to create a UFF model if I remove the while_loop.

Thanks in advance.